# Json Array element extract from json file bigquery

Tags: google-bigquery

I have JSON file like below and facing challenge to extract value in bigquery

```
{
  'c_fields': [
      {
  'id': 34605,
  'value': None,    

 }
]
 }
```

output

```
id     value
24605   null
```

how i will extract value of id and value

Answer (score 0):

If your JSON is in a table column, you could use the JSON FUNCTIONS to accomplish that, [here](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/json_functions) are the docs.

It could be something like:

```sql
WITH test_table AS (
      SELECT '{"c_fields":[{"id":34605,"value":"None"},{"id":34606,"value":"32"}]}' AS json_field
    )

SELECT JSON_EXTRACT(json_value, '$.id') AS id, JSON_EXTRACT(json_value, '$.value') AS value 
FROM test_table, UNNEST(JSON_EXTRACT_ARRAY(json_field, '$.c_fields')) AS json_value
```